# Rock Paper Scissors Keeping Score

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to create a rock paper scissors game that keeps score but when I run this program the score resets each time. What do I need to change so that I can properly keep score?

```
import random

def rockPaperScissors():
    playerScore = 0
    computerScore = 0
    print ""
    p = raw_input("Type 'r' for rock, 'p' for paper or 's' for scissors: ")
    choices = ['r', 'p', 's']
    c = random.choice(choices)
    print ""
    print "Your move:", p
    print "Computer's move:", c
    print ""
    if p == c:
        print "Tie"
    elif p == 'r' and c == 's':
        playerScore += 1
        print "You win"
    elif p == 'p' and c == 'r':
        playerScore += 1
        print "You win"
    elif p == 's' and c == 'p':
        playerScore += 1
        print "You win"
    elif c == 'r' and p == 's':
        computerScore += 1
        print "You lose"
    elif c == 'p' and p == 'r':
        computerScore += 1
        print "You lose"
    elif c == 's' and p == 'p':
        computerScore += 1
        print "You lose"
    else:
        print "Try again"
    print ""
    print "Your score:", str(playerScore)+ ", Computer score:", str(computerScore)

while True:
    rockPaperScissors()
```

Comment: every time you run as in every time you run the script?

Comment: Suggestion from when I taught this assignment: code the choices as the integers 1, 2, 3.  Then (r-c)%3 easily indicates the winner, without having 7 if/else clauses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the function in a loop. The first thing the function does is create a local variable for the score. When the function ends, that score is thrown away. It doesn't persist through multiple calls. You should return the new score and assign the new values to counters:

```
import random

def rockPaperScissors():
    playerScore = 0
    computerScore = 0
    ...
    return playerScore, computerScore

player = 0
computer = 0

while True:
    p, c = rockPaperScissors()
    player += p
    computer += c
    print "Your score:", str(player)+ ", Computer score:", computer
```

Comment: I like this better than global, but I think you should pass the cumulative scores into the function so it prints out the cumulative each time (and don't reset the scores at the top)

Comment: @rbierman - Good point; moved the `print` statement out of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you run the function, you are resetting the scores. Define computerScore and playerScore outside of the function, then it will keep the values even when running the function multiple times. Use global to "import" the global variable into the function scope.

```
playerScore = 0
computerScore = 0

def rockPaperScissors ():
    global playerScore
    global computerScore
    OTHER CODE
```

Comment: `global` is totally unnecessary for this and a terrible crutch to learn.

Comment: I'd recommend using it in this case, simply because it demonstrates the way python works with variables and scopes. Returning the values would be the alternative, although this really is unnecessary for a simple project like this.

Comment: I have never seen a single instance where `global` is the right way to do something.

Comment: So please explain to me why, in this exact case, global is not the way to go? It's a perfect way of demonstrating pythons variable handling (LEGB scoping rules, ...) and is not much cluster. For large-scale-apps I totally agree with you, but right here global, in my opinion, is the way to go

Comment: @NikxDa See [Why is Global State So Evil?](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil)

Comment: I do get that, though this is neither a large-scale application nor a big project. Its just a simple Rock-Paper-Scissors game. Unit testing is not a thing, readability is quite okay, and the output, in this code, is predictable. I'm not saying to always use global - but it might be okay in cases like this. I rest my case.

Comment: This doesn't demonstrate how to work with scopes; it demonstrates how to ignore them. The readability is very low, because you have to look through each function in the code and check to see whether it modifies variables in other scopes.